# Android shrink and grow sequential animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to make a sequential animation in which two buttons shrink until they disappear and then they grow again to their original size.
When I run it the buttons simply disappear without any animations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0"
        android:duration="400"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        /> 

    <scale
        android:startOffset="700"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:duration="400"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
     /> 

</set>
```

```
Animation sgAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shrink_grow);
btPrimary.startAnimation(sgAnimation);
btSecondary.startAnimation(sgAnimation);
```

Comment: what happens when you leave the second `scale` animation out? Do the buttons shrink?

Comment: yes, both animations work individually

Answer (score 17):

```
val scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
    view,
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0.5f),
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0.5f)
)
scaleDown.duration = 2000
scaleDown.repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
scaleDown.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
scaleDown.start()
```

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: I tested the solution - it is simple and efficient!

Answer (score 11):

The following is a grow/shrink animation that works (endlessly).
Setting the animation repeatcount wont work of course, but you can add a counter yourself to stop it.

```
    final ScaleAnimation growAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.15f, 1.0f, 1.15f);
    final ScaleAnimation shrinkAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.15f, 1.0f, 1.15f, 1.0f);

    growAnim.setDuration(2000);
    shrinkAnim.setDuration(2000);

    viewToAnimate.setAnimation(growAnim);
    growAnim.start();

    growAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            viewToAnimate.setAnimation(shrinkAnim);
            shrinkAnim.start();
        }
    });
    shrinkAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            viewToAnimate.setAnimation(growAnim);
            growAnim.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

use   `android:repeatMode="reverse"` `android:repeatCount="infinite"` then it will repeat infinite time i am using it in my tween animation its working

Answer (score 2):

Add this in xml in anim folder.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.15"
        android:toYScale="1.15"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code, this is the working code. copy this shrink_grow.xml in anim folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="false"
android:fillBefore="false"
android:shareInterpolator="true" >

<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillBefore="false"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillBefore="false"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

in the code:

```
Animation sgAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shrink_grow);
btPrimary.startAnimation(sgAnimation);
btSecondary.startAnimation(sgAnimation);
```

Comment: How about a comment and explanation as to why it should work with the animations being sequential?

Comment: I played with the code posted in the question, and made some minor changes, those you can see the differences, differences are 1. using float value in fromXScale etc. 2.fillAfter fillBefore values. I dont know the exact reason why that was not working and why it is working.

Answer (score 1):

```
        final ScaleAnimation growAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5F);
    final ScaleAnimation shrinkAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5F);

    growAnim.setDuration(2000);
    shrinkAnim.setDuration(2000);

    view.setAnimation(growAnim);
    growAnim.start();

    growAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setAnimation(shrinkAnim);
            shrinkAnim.start();
        }
    });
    shrinkAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setAnimation(growAnim);
            growAnim.start();
        }
    });
```